# Way to transport setting of file browser to new version of blender

Tags: file-browser

The point is that, I have created lots of favorite path in blender 2.81. I want to migrate them to blender 2.82.
I have checked blender cloud sync addon, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It transfers info about preference and other settings, but not info about file browser. Any one could give me some idea about this? I think this is very important, otherwise I have to set everything again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I have found way by myself)
In your drive, such as:
C:\Users(Username)\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.82\config
you have three text-files that stores file browser information. copy and paste will do the work.